# Connect to Prestashop API when i used htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop-1.7

I'am trying to access the API of Prestashop but my prestashop is protected by .htaccess.
By reading the prestashop [docs](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/webservice/tutorials/testing-access/)

The problem that prestashop use the basic auth that is the same as .htaccess.

I tried this url :

```
 https://test:test@example.com/api/categories
```

With an HTTP Header `Authorization : Basic <apikey>`

The response with error is the following :

```
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
    <p>This server could not verify that you
        are authorized to access the document
        requested. Either you supplied the wrong
        credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
        browser doesn't understand how to supply
        the credentials required.</p>
    <p>Additionally, a 401 Unauthorized
        error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
```

Do you have an idea of implement the .htaccess authentification and the api key ?
PS: I am using the last version Prestashop 1.7

Comment: _"I tried this url : `https://test:test@example.com/api/categories`
With an HTTP Header `Authorization : Basic <apikey>`"_ - those credentials put into the URL will "translate" into an `Authorization` header already, and you can't send two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your API key as a GET parameter while retaining your .htaccess Basic Auth :

```
https://auth_user:auth_pass@www.example.com/api?ws_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Where auth_user / auth_pass are your already existing Basic Auth info.

Comment: Where do you find this parameter in the doc ?
I tried it is not working, i have `Invalid authentication key format`, i supposed that he resolved the .htaccess but not the api key. I have the same error if do not specify api key.

Comment: I don't think it's documented anywhere but you can easily check yourself that it will work by inspecting the /webservice/dispatcher.php file.
I'm using this method on staging websites from a long time.

Of course I forgot to mention you must include your "other" basic auth credentials in the query string :

https://auth_user:auth_pass@www.example.com/api?ws_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Oh yeah i see but is still not working it appears that after the .htaccess auth the query params are not preserved